# selected nav item in php

Tags: php, navigation

Why this code does not keep an item selected in my navigation?

```
<?php
function navItemSelected($pg)
{
  global $pgname;
  if ($pg == $pgname)
  {
    echo "active";
  }
}
?>

<!-- ===== NAVIGATION ===== -->
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.php" class="<?php echo navItemSelected('home'); ?>">home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Either $pgname doesn't have the value you expect or you get some error trying to echo a function which doesn't return anything but instead runs an echo itself. Try removing the echo when you call the function. You can also try to print $pgname as text to make sure it has the value you expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
  function navItemSelected($pg){
     global $pgname;
     if ($pg == $pgname){
     //echo "active"; Don't echo here
     return "active";
     }
  }
```

Comment: good answer but I would suggest adding a little more clarification for those that might not notice how @user1900715 was calling his function incorrectly.

Comment: @lifo, I was justifying the comment of #span(by showing what exactly should be done),In any programming language when you call any function ,It should be written so that it expects to obtain one or more data values from the calling program.the function #user1900715 wrote did not return any value.As long as his function correction is   concerned #span answer is appropriate.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment, I completely understood your solution. This is an Q/A site and I just felt that a little more explanation goes a long way for others that might not "see" how your solution worked. But in any case, no harm done, it was just a suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

Either `$pgname` doesn't have the value you expect or you get some error trying to echo a function which doesn't return anything but instead runs an echo itself. Try removing the echo when you call the function. You can also try to print `$pgname` as text to make sure it has the value you expect.